# Simon.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I know that you may find this duplicated, but for me it didn't work any of that answers. I'm working in a Simon program like a holiday project, and I'm having trouble with line 41 of this JavaScript code. The thing is that in the HTML file, the ids' exist, but is also getting 'null':

```
var pccolor = [];
var usercolor = [];

function SimonStart() {

    document.getElementById("start").style.opacity = .3;

MakeColors();
}

function MakeColors() {

    var colors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    var randcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    pccolor.push(randcolor);
    LightColor(randcolor, 1000);

}

var randcolor;
var s;

function LightUp() {

    LightColor(pccolor[s]);
    s++;

    if (s < pccolor.length) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            LightUp();

        }, 500);

    }
}

function LightColor(color, TimeOut) {

    var TimeOut = 1000;
    document.getElementById("c" + color).style.opacity = "1"; //doesn't work!
    setTimeout(function () {

        document.getElementById("c" + color).style.opacity = ".3";

    }, TimeOut);

}

function Button(OnClick) {

    LightColor(OnClick);
    usercolor.push(OnClick);
    var i = usercolor.length - 1;
    if (pccolor[i] != usercolor[i]) {

        setTimeout(function () { alert("You lose!"); }, 300);
        pccolor = [];
        usercolor = [];

    } else if (pccolor.length == usercolor.length) {

        usercolor = [];
        pccolor.push(randcolor);
        s = 0;
        setTimeout(function () {

           LightUp();
        }, 500);

    }
}
```

Here is where the .js file ends, and this one is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...

<script type="text/javascript" src="Simon.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Simon.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="centerDiv"> 
        <div class="negro">
            <div class="color" id="c1" onclick="Button (1);"> </div>
            <div class="color" id="c2" onclick="Button (2);"> </div>
            <div class="color" id="c3" onclick="Button (3);"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="negro">
            <div class="color" id="c4" onclick="Button (4);"> </div>
            <div class="color" id="start" onclick="SimonStart ();"></div>
            <div class="color" id="c6" onclick="Button (6);"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="negro">
            <div class="color" id="c7" onclick="Button (7);"> </div>
            <div class="color" id="c8" onclick="Button (8);"> </div>
            <div class="color" id="c9" onclick="Button (9);"> </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody help me please???

Comment: `console.log(color)` is what?

Comment: @epascarello It doesn't have that... I'm just a beginner in this... Now that I've searched it I have a little idea of what that means, but don't know how to put it in the code...

Comment: Well you need to learn how to use the console. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en  So put that line where you are selecting the element. See what the value is when it is written to the developer console.

Answer (score -1):

Place any script tags at the end of the HTML file.

Your code is essentially executing before the DOM is loaded, so to your JavaScript program, there is no HTML to handle.

Comment: The problem is: I press the start button, it lights a random color, the user press that color, and it gets the error... The first time it executes the LightColor function, ir works, but the second time not...